# make grid lines bigger in matlab figures

Tags: matlab, latex, matlab-figure

How can I make grid lines bigger (more fat for printing purpose) in my matlab figures?

I'm including matlab figures in to my `.tex` document after using the following

```
print -depsc testFig.eps
```

to convert the figure into `.eps` for inclusion in my `.tex` doc.

But my grid lines don't look good at all. i.e they appear faint when I print the document. Is there anyway I can increase the size/width of the grid lines?

[image: test figure]

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
set(gca,'LineWidth',10)
```

after "grid on" this should increase the boarders of all axes, including the grid lines.